# Local.xml not making changes to meta descriptions and titles

Tags: local.xml, magento-1.4

I'm trying to edit some page titles and meta descriptions on a custom theme in Magento 1.4.1 (I just inherited this project and it's my first time working with Magento).  I've tried in both `app/design/frontend/default/default1/layout/local.xml` and the theme layout xml files like `layout/customer.xml`.  Here is my `local.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <checkout_cart_index>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="setDescription" translate="title">
                <title>This page sumarizes your shopping cart with Store Name. Use this page to checkout and place your order. Please call us at tel with any questions.</title>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </checkout_cart_index>

    <customer_account_login>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="setTitle" translate="title">
                <title>Login to your account on store.com. Once you login, you may review your account information and make changes easily. To begin, login below.</title>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </customer_account_login>

    <custom_account_forgotpassword>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="setTitle" translate="title">
                <title>Forgot Password</title>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </custom_account_forgotpassword>



</layout>
```

I've cleared and refreshed cache on the admin panel.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the title properly already is set and loaded.
Therefore you cannot change the title - check your php log for messages regarding setTitle errors like this:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function setTitle() on boolean in .../public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Block/Form/Login.php on line 40
```

Fix:

> [theme-name]/template/page/html/head.phtml

```
<title><?php echo ($this->getForcedTitle()) ? Mage::getStoreConfig('design/head/title_prefix').' '.$this->getForcedTitle().' '.Mage::getStoreConfig('design/head/title_suffix') : $this->getTitle() ?></title>
```

Change your `setTitle` updates in local.xml to `setForcedTitle` instead.

Use the same logic for the meta tags.

Comment: Just read that somewhere and seems like the way to go. I will update it and let you know! Thanks!

Comment: Hmmm.  Looks like the handles I was trying to update the page title on are actually just forms, not pages...  So I have to try to find the page handles for all of these things.

Comment: Don't I need to add those methods to some sort of controller or class for them to work??

Comment: for changing page titles, the provided code should be sufficient.